# Migrating a git repo to AWS CodeCommit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services

I've followed the steps [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-migrate-repository.html) and
[here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-https-windows.html#setting-up-https-windows-install-git).

When I run the below commands I get:

`git config --global --edit` displays an edit file containing the lines in the setup guide

`aws configure` shows the tail end of the keys as I would expect to see them.

Yet with the following I get errors:

```
C:\Path\to\repo>git push https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myRepo --all
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403

C:\Path\to\repo>git clone https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myRepo myRepo
Cloning into 'myRepo'...
fatal: unable to access 'https://git-codecommit.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/myRepo/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

Edit: I should add that I've created a User and assigned him to a group which has both of the full access(?) AWSCodeCommit Policies (AWSCodeCommitPowerUse and AWSCodeCommitFullAccess). I created an access key for this user and that's been entered in the credential helper as well.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am having the exact same problem.